# Dividers for labels in css

Tags: html, css

I have total values being displayed in columns, I am trying to divide these values(achieved through labels) using dividers, I looked for dividers online, but was not able to find one for **lables.**

Here's [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/6jhkLh9x/16/)On which I am working on.

> Pls note:- I am trying to achieve the output as follows 
>   700 | 300 | 300 | 200 | 250 | 200 | 250  and rows values should be 850 | 550 | 500 | 300 | 0   |0 (note, this is in column wise now)
>   how do I achieve this?? Please edit my fiddle for any solutions. thanks!!

Sample output expected With the dividers!! [image]
Complete Code Of HTML:-

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
<div id='cols'>
<label>0</label>
<label>0</label>
<label>0</label>
<label>0</label>
<label>0</label>
<label>0</label>
<label>0</label>
</div>
<div id="rows">
<label>0</label>
<label>0</label>
<label>0</label>
<label>0</label>
<label>0</label>
<label>0</label>
</div>
```

Complete Code Of Jquery Function:- 
    var baseEvent;

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
editable: true,
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
eventRender: eventRenderCallback,
viewRender: viewRenderCallback,
defaultView: 'month',
events: [
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 1 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 2 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 3 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 4 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 6 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 7 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 8 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 9 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 10 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 11 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 12 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 13 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 14 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 15 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 16 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 17 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Nov 1 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 2 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 3 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 4 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 5 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 6 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 7 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 8 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 9 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 10 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 11 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 12 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 13 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 14 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 15 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 16 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 17 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 18 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 19 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 20 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 21 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 22 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 23 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 24 2015"},

    {"title":"500","start":"Dec 1 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Dec 2 2015"}
    ]
});

function eventRenderCallback(event,element){
var viewDateMonth = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').getMonth();
if(event.start.getMonth() == viewDateMonth){
    addToTotalCol(event.start.getDay(), parseInt(event.title));
    addToTotalRow(Math.floor(event.start.getDate()/7),      parseInt(event.title));
}
}

function viewRenderCallback(view,element){
$("#cols label").html("0");
$("#rows label").html("0");
if(view.name == "agendaWeek"){
    $("#rows label").hide();
    $("#rows label:nth-child(" + (Math.floor(view.start.getDate()/7)+1) + ")").show();
}else{
    $("#rows label").show();        
}
if(view.name == "agendaDay"){
    $("#cols label").hide();
    $("#rows label").hide();
    $("#cols label:nth-child(" + (view.start.getDay()+1) + ")").show();
}else{
    $("#cols label").show();        
}
}                   

function addToTotalCol(col,num){
var label = $("#cols label:nth-child(" + (col+1) + ")");
label.html(num + Number(label.html()));
}

function addToTotalRow(row,num){
var label = $("#rows label:nth-child(" + (row+1) + ")");
label.html(num + Number(label.html()));
}
```

Comment: I have edited the fiddle and added div's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little tricky because of the calendar (*full-calendar*) component that you are using. It uses a table and therefore it will be difficult for you to determine the precise widths and heights so as to position your totals. Making those responsive in this scenario will become another challenge. Yet another challenge would be when the calendar view is changed from month-view to week-view or day-view. In this case the table structure changes and hence would be difficult to position the totals precisely.

So, you see it is near impossible to do what you want only with CSS. You *will* have to rely on Javascript to do certain parts.

Here is the best you could do with CSS:

*For `cols`:*

```
div#calendar { width: 80vw; table-layout: fixed; }
table.fc-border-separate td > div { height: 60px; }
div#cols { width: 80vw; padding: 11px 0px; }
div#cols label {
    display: inline-block; position: relative;
    padding: 0px 4px; width: calc((80vw / 7) - 4px);
}
div#cols label:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: ''; display: block; position: absolute; 
    top: -50%; right: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #eae1e1; height: 200%; width: 1px;
}
```

*For `rows`:*

```
div#rows { 
    position: absolute; top: 72px; right: 8px; 
    width: 15%; height: auto;
}
div#rows label {
    box-sizing: border-box; display: block; 
    padding: 0px 4px; height: 68px;
}
div#rows label:not(:last-child) { border-bottom: 1px solid #eae1e1; }
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5ht38now/**

The idea here is to reduce the width of the calendar table and use the remaining width to position the row-totals absolutely. Use the calendar-table width for the col-totals. Use `after` psuedo-element on `label`s for the borders. Of course, because of the table involved there would be quite a few widths/heights to be tried with trial-and-error.

.

Comment: Yes, a bit tricky, but your answer is the closest for what I was looking for. Rest I think we should figure it out. So I am going to apply to your answer. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
label {border-left: 1px solid #999; padding-left: 3px;}
label:first-child {border-left: 0;}
```

**Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6jhkLh9x/17/**

Comment: yes praveen, now, the second column, I want to make it as a row with these dividers.. is that possible??

Comment: I would like to add a Little more detailed explanation, I am looking at making the second column into a row and place it at the top right hand corner, and this needs to be responsive.. so, is this possible with labels??

Comment: @user5602805 Yeah, I will try that... Can you put it in picture or something so that it is easy for me to understand?

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar, I have added the expected Output in picture along with my question. So kindly see my question for the picture.

Comment: @user5602805 Boss, that's too much. LoL. Can't make it just with CSS.

Comment: Pls note:- Those dividers, should touch the div, should be in align with the column above and should be responsive... This is what I am expecting!!! looking for suggestions and help from you!!

Comment: alrite... can i make a fiddle with the above picture??? would u able to do the rest???

Comment: @user5602805 Yes, man... I understand. Too much work, could be. So, I don't know exactly how to proceed. :( May be if you can catch me in HackHands, I can take your code and make it work for you in remote. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can either work with a border or do it with the "content" property:

http://jsfiddle.net/6jhkLh9x/18/

```
label:after {
    content: " |"
}

label:last-child:after {
    content: ""
}
```

Comment: I would like to add a Little more detailed explanation, I am looking at making the second column into a row and place it at the top right hand corner, and this needs to be responsive.. so, is this possible with labels??